# How does fork with && and || Operator work?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

I am trying to understand the Output of this Program. But i don't get it. I read about fork and how it works and i tried to understand it, but when i mix it with the && or || Operators i don't understand why the Output is different.
Some Times i get one word, sometimes 2, 3, 4...

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    (fork()&&fork()) || fork();
   printf("Test\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Any Idea how it works?

Comment: Any decent book should have taught you about the [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of the logical operators. They should also have taught you that zero is considered "false" and anything non-zero is "true". And a `fork` manual page would have told you that it returns either zero or a non-zero value. Now use that knowledge.

Comment: Simply don't write weird, artificial code like this and there will be no problems. Anyone who mixes `fork` with a bunch of other operators in the same expression is confused. If you do this for learning purposes, then the only lesson learnt is "don't write really strange code".

Comment: Also note that this exact exercise and problem is apparently common, you should be able to find a lot of information if you just spend some time with your favorite search engine.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept one (and up-vote any) of the answers which you found most helpful.

Comment: thank you for the help guys !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somethings that will help in better understanding this code:

**1. Fork return values -** When you call fork anywhere in your code, you create a new process, and the new process also runs the same code as the parent. The difference between the parent and child process are known from the return value that fork gives. For the child process, fork return value is equal to 0, and for the parent process, it is non-zero.

**2. Short circuit logic evaluation -** When executing boolean logic in C, the execution is run in a short circuit way.

- For a statement  &&  where  and  are 2 expressions that need to be evaluated to either true or false, the second expression () is checked for its trueness only if the first expression () is evaluated to true. This is because, if  is itself false, then regardless of the value of the , the resulting logical expression becomes false, hence making the evaluation of  useless.
- For a statement like  || ,  is executed only if  is false, for a similar reason like above.

In your code snippet, after the first fork() is executed, the child process skips the second fork (due to short circuit of &&) and goes to the third fork(). Resulting in "Test" printed 2 times.
The original parent then encounters the second fork(), and the new child process proceeds to the third fork() and prints Test 2 times again. The parent skips the third fork(), as for it, both the first and second forks are non-zero (short circuit of ||) and prints "Test" once.

Thus "Test" gets printed a total of 5 times.

```
       P1 (fork-1)
      /          \
     P2(fork-2)  P1 (fork-2)
    /  \        /         \
   P3  P2     P4(fork-3)  P1
              /  \
             P4   P5
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on   fork  create  successfully  or not the output should be varied. If all forks are created successfully then 5 times Test should be emerged in output.

1- one output for main thread.(1)

2- main thread create two fork ( firstpart -> (fork() && fork() || secondpart->fork() ) because the first part evaluate as true and the  second part do not execute in main thread. So two output should be seen here.(1+2)

3- every two created fork create a new fork but firstpart do not execute in child but secondpart are executed in each child so two another outputs would be seen in overall 5 outputs should be seen.(1+2+2)

Answer (score 0):

First: Sorry for the Question. I had not done enough research, and i didn't consider each fork as child and as Parent.

What i learned is :

1. The first fork will run and it will create a child.Now we have 2 Processes, Parent returns a number not equal to 0 and Child return 0.
2. Because the **Parent** returned a number not 0 will the fork after && also run, and it will create another child Process. The 1 Child Process returned 0 so it wont run after &&. We now have 3 Processes
3. The fork after || wont run for the **Parent** because it returned a not 0 Number, but it will run for the child because it returned 0 so we end up with 5 Processes. Hope i am right